# need to select records from table based on whether a variable is null or not. If null then check for not equal to condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may sound easy for the folks working on sql on a daily basis this ones eaten lot of my time.
 I have table from which i need to select records based on variable value if value is null set 
status column to not equal to 3, is variable value is not equal to null filter based on the variable value..

```
DECLARE @status int
 set @status  = 1

 SELECT change_set_history_id, files_changed, is_previewed 
    FROM dbo.ChangeSetHistory WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [user_name] = 'djacob' AND 
          [culture] = 'nl-NL' AND
          (@status IS NULL AND [status] <> 3) OR (@status IS NOT NULL AND [status] =     @status) AND
          [approver] = null    AND    
          is_deleted = 0
```

if it try with this part query it works
DECLARE @status int
set @status  = 1
select * from ChangeSetHistory where status = @status and user_name = 'djacob' and culture = 'nl-NL'

Comment: but that does not suit in the your sample code?

Comment: what doesn't suit in my sample code..are u saying the logic itself is wrong

Comment: yep, don't noticed that lacks braces :-)

Comment: braces is not the problem here i have already tried wrapping them up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your `OR` condition with another pair of parentheses:

```
SELECT change_set_history_id, files_changed, is_previewed 
FROM dbo.ChangeSetHistory WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE [user_name] = 'djacob' AND 
      [culture] = 'nl-NL' AND
      ((@status IS NULL AND [status] <> 3) OR (@status IS NOT NULL AND [status] =     @status)) AND
      [approver] IS null    AND    
      is_deleted = 0
```

Without if your condition is equivalent to:

```
    WHERE ([user_name] = 'djacob' AND [culture] = 'nl-NL' AND (@status IS NULL AND [status] <> 3)) OR 
      ((@status IS NOT NULL AND [status] =     @status) AND [approver] = null    AND  is_deleted = 0)
```

Test case:

```
DECLARE @status int
SET @status = 1

    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT NULL [status] UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 [status] UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 [status] UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 [status]
    ) T
    WHERE ((@status IS NULL AND [status] <> 3) OR (@status IS NOT NULL AND [status] = @status));
```

Other problem i see is `[approver] = null` condition. It sohould be `[approver] is null`

Comment: @amitpathak I have updated my answer. `[approver] = null` is also incorrect.

Comment: [approver] = null works fine in sql server thats not an issue moreover for a simple query like this putting so many union statements.. i am not sure on that can this be achieved with case when then, but then setting <> 3 in case when then is causing a problem.

Comment: @amitpathak - `any_value = null` **always** returns `null` in SQL (including when `any_value` _itself_ is null).  Lolo is correct.  (if you're used to several other programming languages, this is a break from most of them, where null is usually at least equal to itself, and returns a straight true/false).  Essentially, the condition is going "Heck if I know it's true!"

Comment: @amitpathak Unions are there only for test case, it's quicker than making table. Moreover `[approver] = null` is not fine. Check it if you don't believe me. For example `SELECT * FROM (SELECT null A) T WHERE T.A = null`

Answer (score 0):

Try to not mix `AND` and `OR` in the same context.

You missed global parentheses on the status condition :

Instead of

```
(@status IS NULL AND [status] <> 3) OR (@status IS NOT NULL AND [status] = @status)
```

It must be

```
((@status IS NULL AND [status] <> 3) OR (@status IS NOT NULL AND [status] = @status))
```

It should resolve your problem:

```
DECLARE @status int
 set @status  = 1

 SELECT change_set_history_id, files_changed, is_previewed 
    FROM dbo.ChangeSetHistory WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [user_name] = 'djacob' AND 
          [culture] = 'nl-NL' AND
          ((@status IS NULL AND [status] <> 3) OR (@status IS NOT NULL AND [status] =     @status)) AND
          [approver] = null    AND    
          is_deleted = 0
```

Comment: Thats what i was thinking initially but after putting the paranthesis also i am not getting any result. I have few records where status column value is 1 that means @ status is not null so the second part of or condition should match, but this query is not yielding them.

Comment: sorry missed the query in last comment